# Can't Mount Folder To Network Share

Tags: mount, samba

I'm trying to mount a folder on my Pi in /mnt/camshare to my network share, as shown below. The network share exists & I can browse to it on a spare Ubuntu machine. FYI the Motion folder itself has 777 permissions, and samba has been installed on my Pi.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo mount.cifs /mnt/camshare //server/raid-array/Motion
Couldn't chdir to //server/raid-array/Motion: No such file or directory
```

I can also physically browse to the folder smb://server/raid-array/Motion from the Raspberry Pi. But I still get the error above.

The end goal is to get fstab to mount it upon startup. I have currently added the lines in my fstab file:

```
//server/raid-array/Motion /mnt/camshare cifs
username=server,password=secret,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

This is also an issue

Comment: BTW, this is not really an rPi specific question, more [Linux&Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for mount is:

`mount -t type <device> <dir>`

You have your device and directory reversed.

Comment: Phil, thank you very very much! I have another thing on top of this. I will update my original post for you to see

Comment: For the second question, take a look at [this Ubuntu troubleshooter](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and then let us know if you still have issues. Also, make sure you put your username/password in an external file, not in fstab.

Comment: I tried it but still have the issue. I even tried the format:
//server/raid-array/Motion /mnt/camshare cifs username=secret,password=secret,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0 as well as the guest version

Comment: Figured it out. I put the IP instead and it worked. I'm running into another issue now with read/write. I'll make another post about it. Thanks for the tips!